# Enable-Migrations is obsolete. Use Add-Migration to start using Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Ok, but what about the following settings that we were using before the Configuration is obsolate?

```
public Configuration()
{
    //AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; //it is Ok for now as default value is true

    //what about the following settings??? 
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; //Attention when using this!!!
    MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations";
    ContextKey = "Demo.Domain.DemoDbContext";
}
```

Where can I set these settings?

Comment: You can use your database migration with package manager console, using commands like Add-Migration Initial and then update-database commands.

Comment: @SalahAkbari I tried to execute `EntityFrameworkCore\enable-migrations -ContextTypeName Demo.ApplicationDbContext -MigrationsDirectory:Migrations\Application`, but encountered obsolote error.

Comment: You don't need to enable it, as I said already just execute my commands in package manager console.

Comment: But I also cannot use any of the migration sommands thta I was using before. Where is the full config of these new commands?

Comment: i would really suggest you spend some time here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 3):

Install `EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package for using commands like Add-Migration and Update-Database in Package Manager Console. You don't need to call Enable-Migrations, and as a side note `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

In the PM Console you can always run the `--help` command with:
`dotnet ef migrations add --help`.

Then you will be able to see all the configuration needed:

```
Usage: dotnet ef migrations add [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
  <NAME>  The name of the migration.

Options:
  -o|--output-dir <PATH>                 The directory (and sub-namespace) to use. Paths are relative to the project directory. Defaults to "Migrations".
  --json                                 Show JSON output.
  -c|--context <DBCONTEXT>               The DbContext to use.
  -p|--project <PROJECT>                 The project to use.
  -s|--startup-project <PROJECT>         The startup project to use.
  --framework <FRAMEWORK>                The target framework.
  --configuration <CONFIGURATION>        The configuration to use.
  --runtime <RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER>         The runtime to use.
  --msbuildprojectextensionspath <PATH>  The MSBuild project extensions path. Defaults to "obj".
  --no-build                             Don't build the project. Only use this when the build is up-to-date.
  -h|--help                              Show help information
  -v|--verbose                           Show verbose output.
  --no-color                             Don't colorize output.
  --prefix-output                        Prefix output with level.
```

For example if you want to set the directory to Migrations (it is the default):

```
dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration --output-dir Migrations
```

Or add a migration while specifying the DbContext:

```
dotnet ef migrations add MyMigration --context MyDbContext
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. At first I locate to the project where my migrations files are located. And then I try to execute this command on cmd and VS Code Terminal, encounter Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found. error. Any idea? Normally I was using cmd for dotnet commands. I also installed EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package before.

Comment: That is a different question, what do you get when typing dotnet --info?

Comment: I see ".NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   3.1.402 ...." message and many things listed without any error. So, can I use cmd as dotnet CLI? I think I can use cmd (or similar one like cmder) as a CLI of any library provided that adding their PATH to environment variables correctly. Is that true?

Comment: Yes it is true, but you must be inside the directory of the migrations

Answer (score 0):

Enable-Migrations was for the older version. new version support to the Add-migration

first enter add-migration "setupName" .

setup name is a any recognizable name eg: add migration "initialSetup"